# SQL fetching different values from 2 rows, where rows have same ids

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to assign values from below table to 2 separate variables :

$a_intro = value from d, if c is empty &
$a_features = value from d, if c is NOT empty

but code below giving me - UNDEFINED VARIABLE $a_features.

```
TABLE STRUCTURE IS :

id1    |    id2     |   a     |     b     |       c     |       d
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 11         22          1           2                        text1
 11         22          1           2            3           text2


$query3 = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE (id1=11 AND id2=22)";

if($result3 = $dbo->query($query3)){

        //echo $result3->fetchColumn()."<br/>";

$data3 = $result3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(empty($data3['c'])){

    $a_intro = $data3['d'];

  //} else if(!empty($data3['c'])){

} else {

    $a_features = $data3['d'];
    //echo "Its not EMPTY";

    }

} else {

    echo "ERROR in SQL Query for fetching Values<br/>";
    echo mysqli_error($dbo);

}
```

Any guess, whats wrong ? Thanks in Advance..

Comment: No need to fetch it twice at `$data3 = $result3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` read http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Comment: Plus you are mixing PDO and mysqli at `mysqli_error($dbo);`

Answer (score 0):

As you hope to get more than one row in your resultset you need to process the result in a loop

> You also appear to be mixing the PDO and MYSQLI API's, That will not work, stick to PDO if that is what you used in your connection to the database

Also your IF's dont cover all the possibilities, and will cause variables to be left undefined and unset in some situations.

```
$query3 = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE (id1=11 AND id2=22)";
$result3 = $dbo->query($query3);
if($result3 === FALSE) {
    echo "ERROR in SQL Query for fetching Values<br/>";
    print_r($dbo->errorInfo();
    exit;
}

// pre define and initialize the variables
$a_intro = [];           
$a_features = [];         


// this loop is implied by your query to get 2 or more results
// However it is nonsence as you are processing 2 rows into 
// scalar variables $a_intro and $a_features
// maybe they shoud be arrays

while ($data3 = $result3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    if(empty($data3['c'])){
        $a_intro[] = $data3['d'];
    } else {
        $a_features[] = $data3['d'];
    }

}
```

> As I dont know what else you are doing with $a_intro and $a_features it is difficult to be more helpful in that respect

Comment: IN fact these are 2 different columns, not IDs, and serving a DYNAMIC DROPDOWNS, so both conditions must be Met, which is TRUE only by using AND operator

Comment: Thanks missed that

Comment: echo mysqli_error($dbo); id not necessary, it can be ignored. Now, can guess, whats wrong, after SQLi is totally removed

Comment: This statement `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` Implies you are using PDO therefore the `mysqli_` object **will not have been instantiated in your connect code** So you cannot just decide to use it. If you connected with PDO then you have to stick to using PDO if it is the other way around and you connected with `MYSQLI_` then you cannot use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`

Comment: print_r($dbo->errorInfo()); and Thanks, i missed the while loop. Thanks TONS :)